# create zsh function with argument for ldapsearch

Tags: terminal, zsh, ldap

I have a couple commands I can run directly on the command line without issue, when I run them and replace `$1` with the actual group name I want to check in LDAP. Now I want to turn it into a parameterized function, and I can't get an error message or an echo to print anything out.

How do I turn the code below into a function I can invoke in zsh by adding it to my .zshrc on the command line?  (Slightly tweaked for public posting)

```
alias ldapuserlookup=" /usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s sub -b 'ou=Groups,o=.com' '(cn=$1)' memberuid | sed 's/memberuid: //g')"
```

Expected output:

```
username1
username2
username3
```

This has to have been asked a million times, but I just don't know what keywords to put into a search that will give me a helpful example. So many are for bash, or don't work with whatever I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll down to the end for the solution, but because it is important to understand what is actually happening, here is the full breakdown.

The answer is three-fold:

##### 1. The command you provided contains an error: There is an extra `)` at the end of the `sed` argument resulting in the following error output:

```
zsh: parse error near `)'
```

(I am guessing this may be a left over from perhaps trying to use `$(...)` syntax)

---

---

##### 2. You are using an alias to execute a command expected to operate on a user-provided argument.In this case you want to use a function instead.

Aliases are essentially just shell helpers and their intended purpose is string substitution of command names, often with appended option flags , for example: `alias ll='ls -al'` , `alias grep='grep --color=auto'` etc.". Additionally, aliases have multiple caveats that can easily break command behavior, but thse go beyond the specific answer to this question.

In your particular case you want to use a **function** instead as these are meant to both accept command arguments and parse them as desired. They are the best of both worlds as they operate in a similar way to aliases - where they can be initialized both globally as well as on the fly inside of one specific terminal - but also have the versatility of a real script, yet without requiring the additional hassle of creating a script file .

In order to reformat your alias as a function you would declare it like so (**NOTE: This is not yet the full solution**):

```bash
ldap_userlookup(){
# It is standard practice to use '_' as separator function names 
 /usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s sub -b 'ou=Groups,o=.com' '(cn=$1)' memberuid | sed 's/memberuid: //g'
}
```

> **NOTE:** Prepending `echo` to a command is a good way of checking how the shell is parsing that specific command. One can also use `set -x` for full debug output, but this can be quite verbose.

Using the following two declarations with prepended `echo`  will illustrate the difference in parsing of the provided argument:

```bash
alias testalias='echo  "/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s sub -b ou=Groups,o=.com (cn=$1) memberuid " '
```

```bash
test_func(){
   echo "/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s sub -b ou=Groups,o=.com (cn=$1) memberuid " }
```

- **BAD:** Using the declared alias and running `testalias argtest` we obtain:

```bash
 /usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s sub -b ou=Groups,o=.com (cn=) memberuid  testarg
```

This is clearly not the desired behavior, as the provided argument gets appended at the end of the command instead of where our command is told to expect the it ( `cn=$1` )

- **GOOD:** Using the function `test_func argtest` we get:

```bash
 /usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s sub -b ou=Groups,o=.com (cn=testarg) memberuid
```

**As you can see, our declared function was able to parse our command line argument `argtest` and then placed at the correct desired position inside of our command, namely as an argument to `cn=` **

---

---

##### 3. **You are using `'` around the variable parameter, and both `bash` and `zsh` obey the rule where variables enclosed in `'` do not get expanded, but those enclosed inside `"` do.**

Here are is how your command (again dropping the pipe for clarity) - even if placed inside of a function - will be parsed depending on the used variable enclosure:

- Using single-quotes `'` around variable inside the function

```bash
test_func(){
    echo "/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s su -b 'ou=Groups,o=.com'"  '(cn=$1)' memberuid 
 }
```

Executing `test_func argtest`

**BAD OUTPUT**:

```
/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s su -b 'ou=Groups,o=.com' (cn=$1) memberuid
```

---

- Reformatting the function with double-quotes `"` instead (leaving the old unneeded `'` quotes, to show that  `"` will override them)

```bash
test_func(){
    echo "/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s su -b 'ou=Groups,o=.com'"  "'(cn=$1)'" memberuid
 }
```

Executing `test_func argtest`

**GOOD OUTPUT:**

```bash
/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap.com -s su -b 'ou=Groups,o=.com' '(cn=argtest)' memberuid
```

---

---

### Full solution:

The full function declaration(`echo` removed, `sed` pipe appended, double quotes used) which should give you the desired behavior is:

```bash
ldap_userlookup () {
       /usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x -h "ldap.com" -s "sub" -b "ou=Groups,o=.com" "(cn=$1)" memberuid | sed 's/memberuid://g'
}
```

Once you test it and it works, you can append it to either your main `~/.zshrc` where it will be loaded into every `zsh` terminal window, or you can create a separate `~/.zsh_functions` file, put this and other custom function defintions inside it, and then use `source ~/.zsh_functions` to load them into your shell as needed.

Comment: The ")" was indeed from a leftover attempt. I'd edit it out at this but since you commented on it I'll leave it for future readers. I tried so many other things, but I didn't realize the difference between ' and ". Thank you!